# Can you interpolate a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ piecewise (by two interpolations)?

Tags: soft-question, interpolation, spline

I am currently trying to improve on-line handwriting recognition. On-line means in this case that I have the information how the symbols are written as a list of $n$ tuples of coordinates $(x(t_i), y(t_i))$ with $i \in 1, ..., n$. I can't really influence the times I get. One idea I have is that symbol recognition might get better, if I get more points / evenly spaced points (spaced by time or probably distance).

So I need an interpolation for $(x(t), y(t))$ with $t \in [t_1, t_n]$.

I know how to calculate cubic splines for functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and I know that they are smooth and easy to calculate.

One way to interpolate the "handwriting-function" $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is to calculate two cubic splines (for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$).

I have a few questions to this:

- Is this a good idea / is there something (that might be) better? (This is the "soft" part of the question)
- Is the function still smooth?
- Do I loose other properties that I'm currently not aware of?

Comment: Sure, if the components x(t), y(t) are smooth, then f is smooth.

Comment: Depends what you mean by smooth. If the first derivative vector is ever zero, the curve might have a sharp corner, even though it's infinitely differentiable.

Comment: Yes, resampling curves using double spline interpolation is commonly done. As mentioned by @bubba, a possible parameterization is by summing the chord lengths. (Parameterization by the true arc length is possible but computationally involved.) Also be sure to segment the curves into pieces where necessary.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve your problem is by using *parametric* cubic splines. As you say, this involves constructing two spline functions $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$. The main problem is that, in order to do this, you have to assign a $t$ value $t=t_i$ to each of your data points $(x_i,y_i)$. How you do this will have a significant affect on the shape of your curve.

There's a bit more information in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686464/how-to-construct-a-parametric-cubic-b-spline/686632#686632), including a link that might be useful.

Some specific answers:

(1) Is it a good idea. Yes, I think so. It's not a new idea. It has been used many times before, and its problems are fairly well understood.

(2) Is the curve smooth. In a mathematical sense it is. A parametric cubic spline will have two continuous derivatives, when considered as a mapping from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. But from a geometric or aesthetic point of view, it might not be "smooth". Specifically, at places where the derivative vector $(x', y')$ is zero (if any), there might be sharp corners in the curve. This doesn't happen very often in practice, though. Nasty little loops will occur if you choose the $t_i$ values badly. Again, this is a loss of aesthetic smoothness, not a loss of mathematical smoothness (differentiability).

(3) Do you lose anything. Well, in some sense, you lose your direct connection with the input data, because the $t_i$ values mentioned above are entirely fabricated.